# How to expand column with parentheses in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 4 Values data as output of a function. Here's my data

```
Name         Grade
usia         (75,78,90,52)
shdh         (85,68,60,72)
fbjg         (95,58,65,66)
```

Here's what I want

```
Name         Math    English   Physics    Chemistry
usia           75         78        90           52
shdh           85         68        60           72
fbjg           95         58        65           66
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DataFrame` constructor with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for remove original column `Grade`:

```
import ast

#if strings inputs instead tuples
#df['Grade'] = df['Grade'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

cols = ['Math','English','Physics','Chemistry']

df[cols] = pd.DataFrame(df.pop('Grade').tolist(), index=df.index)
print (df)
   Name  Math  English  Physics  Chemistry
0  usia    75       78       90         52
1  shdh    85       68       60         72
2  fbjg    95       58       65         66
```